# Sorting all the values (which are arrays) of a Dictionary of Arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary of arrays, created by grouping an array by `date` (elements of the array have `date` and `time` properties which are both **`Date`** objects):

```
let groupedData = Dictionary(grouping: array, by: { $0.date })
```

Now I want each array in the dictionary to be sorted by `time` property. What do you propose?

Comment: Sort them. What’s the problem?

Comment: Say I want to show them in a sectioned-table. Each section represents a day. In each section I want to show the rows sorted by time of the day.

sep18:
- 8:20
- 11:40

sep19:
- 9:05
- 13:30

Comment: @matt How? You mean like iterating on dictionary key/values, sorting each and assigning them to a different dictionary? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Well, you _could_ have sorted the array by `time` beforehand, since the `grouping` initializer will mop up arrays in the order in which they occur. But since you failed to do that, yes, just iterate the keys, fetch the values, sort, and reassign back into the same dictionary.

Comment: Oh didn't know that it would not mess with the order. Sorting beforehand did the trick. Thanks @matt

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to display your array grouping your objects by same day to display in sections in your table view, you don't a dictionary, what you need is a 2D array. You can group your objects first sorting them by date, then you can  use collection's method reduce(into:) and check if the last array last element date property is in same day as the current element date. Based on that you will append the object to the last collection of the result of you will append a new array with that element:

```
struct Obj {
    let date: Date
}
extension Obj: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { return "Obj(date: \(date.description(with: .current))" }
}
```

---

I created a custom initialiser to make if easier to generate some date objects for testing:

```
extension Date {
    init?(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int, hour: Int) {
        guard let date = DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: year, month: month, day: day, hour: hour).date else { return nil }
        self.init(timeInterval: 0, since: date)
    }
}
```

---

```
let objs = [(2019, 1, 26, 6),
            (2019, 1, 26, 7),
            (2019, 1, 27, 10),
            (2019, 1, 27, 11),
            (2019, 1, 28, 13),
            (2019, 1, 28, 14),
            (2019, 1, 28, 15)]
            .compactMap(Date.init)
            .map(Obj.init)
```

---

```
let groupedData: [[Obj]] = objs.sorted{ $0.date < $1.date }
    .reduce(into: []) {
        if let date = $0.last?.last?.date,
            Calendar.current.isDate(date, inSameDayAs: $1.date) {
            $0[$0.index(before: $0.endIndex)].append($1)
        } else {
            $0.append([$1])
        }
}
```

---

```
groupedData.forEach {
    print($0)
}
```